# How do I interpret the result of individual survival probabilities in Survival Analysis in R?

Tags: r, probability, survival, cox-model

I have developed a survival model using Cox Regression. The aim is to obtain individual probabilities of survival on a given date or time. Now the steps used are:

`fit<-coxph(Surv(time,status=0)~`$X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+.....+X_p$)

```
summary(fit)
cox_fit<-survfit(fit)
cox_lp_predict<-predict(fit,type='lp')
basehaz_cox<-basehaz(fit)

individual_probability_at_t1<-as.data.frame(exp(-b_1)^(exp(cox_lp_predict)))
individual_probability_at_t2<-as.data.frame(exp(-b_2)^(exp(cox_lp_predict)))
```

`fit<-coxph(Surv(time,status=0)~`$X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+.....+X_p$)Here status =0 because we want to analyse those observations where status=0, infact in my case status is churn flag=0$=>$ No churn,1$=>$Churn

`cox_lp_predict<-predict(fit,type='lp')`#This step is to find $X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2+.....+x_p\beta_p$ for each observation

`basehaz_cox<-basehaz(fit)`#Now let's say after obtaining the base hazard we get the cumulative base hazard i.e $H_0(t)$ at $t=t_1$ is $=b_1$

And
let's say after obtaining the base hazard we get the cumulative base hazard using `basehaz_cox<-basehaz(fit)` i.e $H_0(t)$ at $t=t_2$ is $=b_2$

`individual_probability_at_t1<-as.data.frame(exp(-b_1)^(exp(cox_lp_predict)))`This is in line with the formula $S(t|X)=exp(-\int_0^t h_0(t)dt)^{exp(\beta_1x_1+...\beta_px_p)}=S(t|X)=exp(-H_0(t))^{exp(\beta_1x_1+...\beta_px_p)}$

Now my question is that when we obtain an appended dataframe i.e

```
Merged_individual_prob_at_t1_t2<-merge(individual_probability_at_t1$Probability_at_t1,individual_probability_at_t2$Probability_at_t2)
```

We get a table like this :

```
Serial No.   Prob(T>230)  Prob(T>360)   Prob(T>500)
1            0.1125       0.3455        0.3221
2            0.2344       0.3244        0.2877
3            0.2556       0.4456        0.3211
```

And so on.

My question exactly here for certain observations like the ones I show above the survival probability increases for a certain duration of time and then it reduces like the above table. Mind it most of the observations show a decreasing survival probability over the three time instances calculated but for some of them this **increasing trend** for a certain period comes and then it again starts reducing. My question is why does this happen?
Is my approach correct?
If not rectify me anywhere,please help.

Comment: The question as it is presented now is pretty messy. You should run diagnostics and figure out exactly where the logic breaks down and ask a specific question for that specific step.

Comment: First how to obtain individual probabilities of each individual at time t?Second, how do I interpret the increase and then decrease in survival probabilities of certain individuals over time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get individual probabilities from a fitted Cox model from the **survival** package in R, you can use the `survfit()` method, e.g.,

```
fm <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 0) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = your_data)
sfit <- survfit(fm, newdata = your_data)
summary(sfit, times = 230)
```